# How do I check if a variable is null using a If Controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a session variable and I want to use an If Controller to check if it is null and run a request to grab a new one if it is. I tried a few things...

```
"${session}" == "\${session}"
"${session}".length > 0
```

But none seem to work.

How do I check if a variable is set using an If Controller

Answer (score 2):

You may try `'${__javaScript(vars.get("session") != null)}`

Please see [the link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you can use [__isVarDefined()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) function which returns `true` if the JMeter Variable is defined (not `null`) and `false` otherwise

Demo:

[image: JMeter isVarDefined Demo]

Comment: can u show a sample usage ? , I have tried "${__isVarDefined(variableName}}" but not works.